# How to add hover for ::before

Tags: angularjs, css, kendo-ui

Iam using kendo Calendar

this is the html

```
> <table> <tr>  <td role="gridcell" class=""><a tabindex="-1"
> class="k-link" href="#"  data-value="2015/11`enter code here`/1" title="Tuesday,
> December 01, 2015"><div   class="exhibition">1</div></a></td> </tr>
> </table>
```

On hover "k-state-hover" class is adding to td

```
<td role="gridcell" class="k-state-hover"><a tabindex="-1"
class="k-link" href="#" data-value="2015/11/1" title="Tuesday,
 December 01, 2015"><div class="exhibition">1</div></a></td>
```

I want to change the colour of "k-state-hover" for "exhibition" div

I tried like this:

```
.exhibition::before:hover{
background-color:"red";
}
```

but its not working

Answer (score 5):

Use `.exhibition:hover::before` instead of `.exhibition::before:hover`

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply :hover on a dom element, not a pseudo-element like :before. So anyway you can only write ".exhibition:hover::before"
But in your case if I understand well, you want to change the background color of the ::before of the .exhibition div when the class k-state-hover is applied, so you only need :

```
.k-state-hover .exhibition::before{
    background-color:red;
}
```

`